# How to conver raw I/Q data to their numerical values

Tags: matlab, iq

I would like to know how can I convert a raw IQ data file (that was captured using (sdr)) to it's numerical value using matlab. something like this e.x (I=19.5 , Q=90). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the amplitude and phase of of your I/Q values? If so then here it is,

```
I = 19.5;
Q = 90;

amplitude = sqrt(I.^2 + Q.^2);
phase = atan(Q./I);
```

Comment: OK thanks Mr. Amahmud but how can i read the file to get the I and the Q in the first place .